# Сравнение элементов массивов в foreach

Tags: xml, php, foreach

Добрый день.

Нужно распарcить xml.

Извлекаю данные:

```
foreach ($Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Items->Item as $Item) {
                $ID=$Item['ID'];  // извлекаем ID и выводим колонкой

                echo ($ID." |<br>");
                }
```

Нужно сравнить с выборкой, полученной из того же xml, типа как:

```
foreach($Catalogs->Catalog[0]->Dictionaries->Dictionary[1]->DictionaryItem[0]->Elements->Element as $Element)
    {
        if ($Element['ID']==$ID) {echo "Найдено совпадение";}

    }
```

**Задача:**
Если элемент из массива первого форейча совпадает с любым элементом массива второго форейча (`$Element['ID']`), то выводим "Найдено совпадение" при каждом совпадении одного из элементов `$ID` с любым элементом `$Element['ID']`.

**В итоге нужно получить такую запись:**

> ```
> 3432 |Найдено совпадение
> 4345 |
> 5423 |Найдено совпадение
> 4532 |Найдено совпадение
> 6543 |
> 56345 |Найдено совпадение
> ```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем именно сложности возникли.

`$CODES[] = $Item['ID']; if (in_array($CODES, $Element['ID'])) { echo $Element['ID']; }`?

Или задачу вообще стоит решать на стороне СУБД. Пишите более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, упростив его. СУБД тут не при чем.

Comment: Если решать задачу "в лоб", то можно и вложить `foreach (...Element as $Element)` в `foreach (...Item as $Item)`, но лучше избегать такой практики и обратить внимание на функцию `in_array()`